# Emberjs multiple TextField issue

Tags: ember.js

I have a weird bug with the `TextField` that I don't understand. This is the first time I am working with `TextField`, before I was using `{{input}}` instead, but for the sake of form validations etc I needed to change.

My problem is that I have two `TextField` and when I enter something in the first one, the second one also has the value.. If I enter 'Hello' in the first, the second will also filled with 'Hello', like they are linked somehow..

This is my template login.hbs:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label hidden">Mandatory field</label>
    {{view "input" type="text" classNames="form-control" value=username placeholder="Please enter username"}}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label hidden">Mandatory field</label>
    {{view "input" type="password" classNames="form-control" value=username placeholder="Please enter password"}}
</div>
```

My views/login.js :

```
export default Ember.View.extend({
    actions: {
        submit: function() {
            this.get('controller').send('login');
        }
    }
});
```

My views/input.js
This one is just some DOM check.

```
export default Ember.TextField.extend({
    focusOut: function( e ) {
        var $tag = Ember.$(e.currentTarget);
        if (!$tag.val()) {
            if(!$tag.parent().hasClass('has-error')) {
                $tag.parent().find('.control-label').removeClass('hidden');
                $tag.parent().addClass('has-error');
            }
        } else {
            if($tag.parent().hasClass('has-error')) {
                $tag.parent().find('.control-label').addClass('hidden');
                $tag.parent().removeClass('has-error');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Did I do something wrong ??

Thanks.

Comment: Both of ur view's value property is set to username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your inputs have their value bound to the same property. Try using a different property for the 2nd field. Since the 2nd field is labeled as 'password' I'd recommend going with that. Just replace `value=username`with `value=password`on the 2nd input.

Comment: OH MY GOD !! I should have seen that ! I feel kinda stupid now.. This is of course working fine :) thanks !!! and thansk to blessenm too !